# Turning Off Default Schema in MySQL WorkBench

Tags: mysql-workbench

I accidentally clicked on "Set as Default Schema" button and it turned the database name into bold black in color. How do I switch it back to the normal one? Please advise.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

You can edit the connection and under the Advanced tab there is textbox called Others. Remove the following line: DbSqlEditor:LastDefaultSchema=the_default_schema

I am using MySQL workbench 6.4.

Answer (score 8):

There's no "normal" case. You can quickly switch the default schema by double clicking on the schema node in the tree. But if you really want no default schema create a dummy one, make that the default and delete it.

Comment: You mean I should double click on the database which has turned bold (Black in color) and this will remove it from the default schema ?

Comment: No, create a new schema, make this default and remove it. This will also automatically remove the current default. It's a bit hackish that way, but enough for such an extremely rarely needed feature.